# PowerShell "get-command *services*" equivalent with Terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash

I’m new to the Terminal and would like to know if there’s a way to find certain command names within the terminal instead of trying to look them up online and through various sites.

I’m enjoying the `--help` and `man` support for the command that I know, but I would like to see what commands are out there and discover new commands.

Comment: Type this command `ls /bin /sbin /usr/bin /usr/sbin` and you should get just about every command on your system.

Comment: you're looking for apropos

Answer (score 1):

There is a `bash` builtin named `compgen` that can display all possible completions which means that you can see all the commands which are enabled for completions.

To see all commands runnable by you, you can do:

```
compgen -c
```

If you want to find all commands having e.g. `bash` in their names, you can do:

```
$ compgen -c | grep 'bash'
dh_bash-completion
bashbug
bash
rbash
```

Here are the list of options you can use with `compgen`:

```
alias       Alias names. Specified as -a.
builtin     Names of shell builtin commands. Specified as -b.
command     Command names. Specified as -c.
directory   Directory names. Specified as -d.
export      Names of exported shell variables. Specified as -e.
file        File names. Specified as -f.
function    Names of shell functions.
group       Group names. Specified as -g.
job         Job names, if job control is active. Specified as -j.
keyword     Shell reserved words. Specified as -k.
service     Service names. Specified as -s.
user        User names. Specified as -u.
variable    Names of all shell variables. Specified as -v.
```

`compgen` accepts more parameters through the `-A` option. Check `compgen` and `complete` entries from `man bash` to get more idea.